# APK Assets not loaded on Kindle Fire HD

Tags: android, c++, apk, kindle-fire, libzip

I have developed an App for the Amazon Kindle Fire HD.
While distributing I got a report from amazon that its not running on almost all Kindle devices and a blackscreen is displayed. They send me a logcat log file and I found out that it's not possible to load some assets directly from APK file (accessing via C++, zlib and libzip).

Everything is running fine if I start it via Eclipse.

Any idea whats going wrong?
Thanks!

**Update:**

I found out that this is related to `zip_open()`. This call fails and returns `ZIP_ER_INCONS`

Comment: Experiencing the same issue on the Moto X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered exactly this problem with newer versions of lib zip. Amazon must do something to the APK which causes lib zip to think it is corrupt.

I solved the issue by using an older version of the lib zip available here:

https://github.com/julienr/libzip-android

Comment: Thank you. I already fixed this by loading the assets via Java code (and passing them to c++). This is also a lot faster than loading the assets via libzip.

Comment: Did you use version `0.9.3` of this library?  It's since been updated to a newer version.